# Stuck in infinite loop while trying to intercept form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing Javascript/JQuery code, where I want to intercept the form submission before submitting it because I need to check if the fields are valid.

So I block the default event from happening, check what I want to, then fire the event again if everything is ok. Problem is, this triggers the exact same function and I get stuck in an infinite loop.

Is there a way around this? I can think of work arounds, but they are, after all, work arounds and not the most elegant of solutions.

Here is my code:

```
            $("#register_form").submit(function(event)  {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log('form submit attempt');
                checkUsername();
                $("#register_form").submit();
            });
```

Comment: remove the second and the second last line? (or prevent the default only at the end of the func if something isn't ok)

Comment: is the checkUsername() function contains ajax call?
if yes then you need to remove $("#register_form").submit();
and add this removed line to the success of the ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to stop the form submitting if there are errors, you need to `return false` from the function. You'll need to make sure that the `checkUsername()` function returns bool.

Try this...

```
$("#register_form").submit(function(event)  {                    
    if(checkUsername())
        return true;

    return false;       

});
```

Or even better...

```
$("#register_form").submit(function(event)  {                    
        return checkUsername();                    
});
```